# App loads slow - too much static string resources?

Tags: android, database, static, resources

I am working on a e-shop type application with more than 500 cathegories. Cathegory is basically a name-value pair and its not going to change. How should I store this data? Currently I am using string arrays in strings.xml resources file (one for names, one for values). The application now starts like 5 seconds or more, which is very slow. Is this because of too much resources? Do they all get loaded at startup?

Should I use database for this? Basically I need this data only later in the app, when creating a "query" , you select from all the cathegories, certainly not at start up..

If so, where should I put all those strings to have it bulk inserted at first app run? A class? wouldnt this still be slowing down every startup, as the class has to get loaded? Is it possible to load resource string array only in the activity where I will construct the query? (given they all get somehow loaded at startup, which it seems)..

Thanks!

Comment: you can use database for that.. and when app loaded copy database to device.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQLite, and query strings whenever you want, hence it doesn't affect to the performance.

read more at:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

and

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: i know how to use databases... how do you think i should deliver these static data with the apk?